# I have to arrange the elements in this array from greatest to smallest using 2 methods, but the output is completely different

Tags: c, sorting, methods

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int IndexOfMaxInRange(int ra[], int first, int last)
{
    int index = first;
    int max = ra[first];
    for(int i = first+1; i < last; i++)
    {
       if(ra[i] > max)
          {
              index = i;
          }
    }
    return index;
}

void SwapElement(int ra[], int iOne, int iTwo)
{
    int temp = ra[iOne];
    ra[iTwo] = ra[iOne];
    ra[iOne] = temp;
}

void SortArray(int ra[],int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    SwapElement(ra, i, IndexOfMaxInRange(ra, i, (length-1)));
    }
}
int main(void)
{
   int ra[5] = {2,5,8,3,4};
   int length = sizeof (ra) / sizeof (ra[0]);
   SortArray(ra, length);
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
     printf("%d ", ra[i]);
   }
   return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I am supposed to arrange the elements from greatest to smallest, but my output is: "2 5 5 2 4"
I know I am doing something wrong, but I can't put my eye on it, thanks in advance for all the feedback.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `SwapElement` doesn't look right. Check your logic there.

Comment: When you found the program doesn't work as expected what did you do next? Did you do any debugging by running your program in a debugger and stepping through the code line by line to investigate? If so, what did you find? Where did things start going wrong? Learning to debug effectively is a crucial skill (asking someone else to debug on SO should be a last resort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the swap was incorrect, you lost `ra[iTwo]` in the process. Change to

```
void SwapElement(int ra[], int iOne, int iTwo)
{
    int temp = ra[iOne];
    ra[iOne] = ra[iTwo];
    ra[iTwo] = temp;
}
```

---

Second error is that you are not updating the current max in `IndexOfMaxInRange`

```
if(ra[i] > max)
{
    max = ra[i];
    index = i;
}
```

---

Now it should work.